# Bash string comparison not working on BusyBox

Tags: bash, string-comparison, busybox

I don't understand why this bash script won't work on BusyBox v1.29.3 () built-in shell (ash).

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

MODE=$(cat /etc/config/wireless | grep 'option mode') #not working
#MODE="option mode 'sta'" ==> this works
echo $MODE

MCHECK="option mode 'sta'"

echo $MCHECK

if [ "$MCHECK" = "$MODE" ];then
   ping -c3 www.google.com > /dev/null
   a=$?
   echo $a
   if [ $a -eq 0 ];then
      echo "ok"
   else
      echo "fail"
   fi
else
    echo "no sta mode"
fi
```

It works correctly if I "force" the string with a variable.( the #MODE)
I imagine there are some characters in the cat returned variable that create a different string.

I always got "no sta mode" so the if won't return true.
The option mode in etc/config/wireless is the same as the string to compare.

Cannot find what am I missing..?

Comment: Replace `[[ == ]]` with `[ = ]` in the `if` expression. `[[` is Bash syntax. `[` is Bourne shell syntax.

Comment: Enclose the resulting string with double quotes, `MODE="$(cat /etc/config/wireless | grep 'option mode')"`

Comment: I edited because there was a mistake

@Anubis Thanks, I tried, but is not working

Comment: The problem is `cat /etc/config/wireless | grep 'option mode'` does not give what you need. Did you verify this manually? The output should be "identical" to the `$MCHECK` content.

Comment: ok I found it.
cat /etc/config/wireless | grep 'option mode' return 8 space before "option mode 'sta'"
If I change MCHECK="option mode 'sta'" to MCHECK="8spaceshereoption mode 'sta'"

This works!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was following gives a string with leading zeros.

```
MODE="$(cat /etc/config/wireless | grep 'option mode')"
```

Following gives the same result without leading spaces.

```
MODE="$(cat /etc/config/wireless | sed -n 's/\s*\(option mode.*\)/\1/p'"
```

Comment: even simpler, `sed 's/^\s*//g'`
;)

Comment: @jan6 It will trim leading zeros in "any" line. But that's not what OP needs.

Comment: sed `'1s/^\s*//'` then

Comment: @jan6 It will trim leading zeros only on the first line, but still output all the remaining lines without modification (maybe you wanted to suggest `sed '1s/^\s*//;q'`).
However I don't know about the exact content of the file OP is interested in, but it is very likely that the target line won't appear as the first line because it seems this line is describing an option for some configuration, which should have been given in a line before.